# C++ - Why is my else-statement in an if-else-statement ignored?

Tags: c++, if-statement, visual-c++

Well, I've come across a strange problem.

Since adding the spdlog library to my project and adjusting all log output accordingly, all else blocks of my if-else statements are ignored. The log output has been replaced by a search-and-replace procedure with a simple regex pattern (printf-style to fmtlib-style).

spdlog: https://github.com/gabime/spdlog

After some debugging, I have now written the following very simple test function:

```
void dbg_test() {
    bool success = false;

    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(!success, "Sanity check");

    // This works
    if (success) {
        LOG_ERROR("Successful");
    } else {
        LOG_ERROR("Unsuccessful"); // Log's written
    }

    // This doesn't work
    if (success)
        LOG_ERROR("Successful (w/o)");
    else
        LOG_ERROR("Unsuccessful (w/o)"); // Log's missing
}
```

Depending on the value of "success" the following now happens (BOOST_ASSERT_MSG is adapted accordingly): If `success == true`, "Successful" and "Successful (w/o)" is written to the log. If `success == false`, "Unsuccessful" is written, but "Unsuccessful (w/o)" is not.

Of course I also checked the logging and wanted to end the program with exit(0) instead of writing logs, but this code didn't work either:

```
void dbg_test() {
    bool success = false;

    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(!success, "Sanity check");

    // This works
    if (success) {
        LOG_ERROR("Successful");
    } else {
        exit(0);
    }

    // This doesn't work
    if (success)
        LOG_ERROR("Successful (w/o)");
    else
        exit(0);
}
```

For compilation and debugging I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.5.0). The corresponding project folder was created with CMake 3.13.4.

What could be the reason for this?

---

**Edit**

Macro definition for `LOG_ERROR`:

```
#define LOG_ERROR(...) SPDLOG_ERROR(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: What is `LOG_ERROR`? How is the macro (I assume) defined?

Comment: Almost certainly a poorly defined `LOG_ERROR` macro, but without seeing the macro definition who can be sure?

Comment: My crystal ball says that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros) will be useful

Comment: As I wrote below, I also checked this and replaced LOG_ERROR in the appropriate lines that should be handled with exit(0) (first for the code that doesn't work, then for the working one, otherwise I would never reach the non-functioning code).

However, this is the definition of the macro: `#define LOG_ERROR(...) SPDLOG_ERROR(__VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: And what's `SPDLOG_ERROR`? You don't need to expand the whole thing yourself, you know. VC support a `/E` flag to preprocess only.

Comment: @M.M I've read the thread you linked and am taking a look at it right now. Obviously that could be the reason why even my second code failed (as I still use macros in the if-block).

Comment: @StoryTeller Yep, it seems like this is the problem. I didn't know about this case of error source. SPDLOG_ERROR expands to `if (spdlog::default_logger_raw()->should_log(spdlog::level::err))                                                                                                         \
    spdlog::default_logger_raw()->log(spdlog::source_loc{SPDLOG_FILE_BASENAME(__FILE__), __LINE__, SPDLOG_FUNCTION}, spdlog::level::err, __VA_ARGS__)` which contains an if-statement already. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: No, just accept an answer

Comment: Pretty bad mistake from what purports to be modern style library.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently creating an issue there to tell them about that error. I will try to fix it myself later but I'm not that convenient with GitHub fork, pull-requests, etc.

Comment: Downvote reversed. This question is very clear - the problem can only be in the macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lot's of fancy code but they can't get a simple macro right. This isn't the LOG_ERROR macro (I couldn't find that) but it illustrates the problem

```
#define SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL(logger, level, ...) \
    if (logger->should_log(level)) \
        logger->log(spdlog::source_loc{SPDLOG_FILE_BASENAME(__FILE__), __LINE__, SPDLOG_FUNCTION}, level, __VA_ARGS__)
```

should be

```
#define SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL(logger, level, ...)  \
    do \
        if (logger->should_log(level)) \
            logger->log(spdlog::source_loc{SPDLOG_FILE_BASENAME(__FILE__), __LINE__, SPDLOG_FUNCTION}, level, __VA_ARGS__) \
    while (false)
```

The `do ... while` trick ensures that the output of the macro can be used as a simple statement. That's not true of the if statement that the original macro output which, as you found, is going to mess up any `if ... else` statement it finds itself in.

Maybe you could join the project and push this fix.

Comment: Well based on the comments above this seems to be the explanation. LOG_ERROR expands to SPDLOG_ERROR which expands to SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL